# Handle Multiple UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uislider

I have 4 UISlider with minimum value 0, Maximum value 10. I have one constant value(Ex:20).

My goal is sum of 4 slider value doesn't go above that constant value.

Ex: if i drag and set to maximum value of 1st and 2nd slider(i.e 10), Now the sum of 4 slider is 20.

I don't want to allow other 2 sliders(3rd,4th) to increase. if i decrease any slider(1st or 2nd) value means then i can allow them(2,3,4) to increase  sliders values.

help me to achieve this.

[You can see this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD6wm.png)

[You can see this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPluL.png)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are saying.. the language you have used is difficult to understand and follow. Please try to clarify.. Based on what I understand you want each slider to have a max value of 10.. but the SUM of all 4 cannot be above 20... is that correct?

Comment: please share any code you have written for this problem

Comment: What about if the user starts with all four sliders and 0 and then they slide the 4th slider to 10 and then the 2nd slider to 10. Do you then want to prevent sliders 1 and 3 from being moved at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `@IBAction sliderValueChanged`, calculate the sum of all sliders. If the sum is greater the the maximum, just reset the value of the "causing" slider (e.g. the one that is currently being dragged by the user) to the maximum allowed value.

```
// ...
let maxSum = 20
// ...
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let sum = slider1.value + slider2.value + slider3.value + slider4.value // better: use outlet collection
    if (sum > maxSum) {
        let overflow = sum - maxSum
        sender.value = sender.value - overflow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a central method that all the sliders call for the `valueChanged` event.

In that method, sum the values of all the sliders. As the sum changes, adjust the max of all the sliders so that increasing any one slider can't exceed your sum total value. (Each slider's new max would be the the difference between it's current value and max_sum_total - current_sum_total.

So if you set all the sliders to 5, your method would adjust the max for all the sliders to 5.

If Slider A was at 10, Slider B was at 5, and the others were at 0,

```
Slider A max would be MIN((20 - (A+B+C+D) - A), 10) //5
Slider B max would be MIN((20 - (A+B+C+D) - B), 10) //10
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for rough start. i am using single method to handle all 4 UISliders. you can refactor code as you want

[image]

```
@IBAction func touchDrag(_ sender: UISlider) {

        switch sender {
        case slider1:
            let f1 = (sender.value + slider2.value)
            let f2 = (slider3.value + slider4.value)
            if  f1 + f2  > 20 {
                sender.value = 20 - (slider2.value + slider3.value + slider4.value)
            }
        case slider2:
            let f1 = (slider1.value + sender.value)
            let f2 = (slider3.value + slider4.value)
            if  f1 + f2  > 20 {
                sender.value = 20 - (slider1.value + slider3.value + slider4.value)
            }
        case slider3:
                let f1 = (slider1.value + slider2.value)
                let f2 = (sender.value + slider4.value)
                if  f1 + f2  > 20 {
                sender.value = 20 - (slider1.value + slider2.value + slider4.value)
            }
        default:
                let f1 = (slider1.value + slider2.value)
                let f2 = (slider3.value + sender.value)
                if  f1 + f2  > 20 {
                sender.value = 20 - (slider1.value + slider2.value + slider3.value)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have the exact same logic in all 4 cases. Why?

Comment: I know it can be more simplified. 
if you have a closure look then you will find that every case have different calculation.
This is to remove the slider flicker problem in Andreas Oetjen's answer by the appropriate value to sender